# Search and Replace Script Loader in Head Only Works in Footer

Tags: functions, filters, javascript

I've got a function that uses `script_loader_tag` filter to search and replace adding `asynch="asynch"` attribute. It works.

I don't want this doing anything in the footer, but rather the header alone. The following code is working but inverse and I'm stumped. It's only adding the attribute to scripts in the footer...

```
function async_js_mssa(){
    //function to add async to all scripts
    function js_async_attr($tag){

    // Add async to all remaining scripts
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" src', $tag );
    }
    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_async_attr', 10 );
    }
add_filter('wp_head', 'async_js_mssa');
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but you can try to `add_filter('script_loader_tag', ...)` like you would any other filters, and then in wp_head call `remove_filter('script_loader_tag',...)` Since you are calling script_loader_tag in wp_head, it will only apply to anything that runs AFTER wp_head

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, Czerspalace. I modified my code and it effectively looks for conditions to be met. If I alternate the priority it works. But it's still only working in the footer, not adding to the head.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Just posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, it was what I tried to explain in my comment. Again, this is just a guess.

```
function js_async_attr($tag){ 
   // Add async to all remaining scripts
   return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" src', $tag );
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_async_attr');

function remove_js_async_head(){
    // function to add async to all scripts
    remove_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_async_attr');
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_js_async_head', 100);
```

Comment: I will give it a go tomorrow. Just left the office. Thank you for the feedback. Cheers!

Comment: Oh that's beautiful. Thank you so much, Czerspalace!